# Does Jekyll permit using just the title of a post as the URL?

Tags: ruby, jekyll

Does Jekyll gem allow using just the title of the post as the URL?

For example, if I have a markdown file named like `first-post-ever.markdown`, can I get the route to be like `something.com/first-post-ever`? Without the date info.

Even `something.com/first-post-ever.html` is fine by me, but without `.html` is preferred.

In the config file, I tried `permalink: /:title.html` and `permalink: /:title`, but neither worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is allowed. Your config is correct, try removing the generated static pages (`_site` folder) then restart the jekyll server.

Comment: You were pretty much right. Only thing I had to change we my file name. Regardless of the url setting, the file name convention of date-title should be followed. For example, `first-post-ever.html` should be `2013-01-29-first-post-ever.html`.

Comment: If you want to "remove" this convention, you can use pages instead of posts. I wouldn't do it, tho. :)

Comment: Is there a way to do that in one folder only? Say I have `/posts` and `/projects` I don't want dates in projects.